# Dial up connection using vb6

Tags: vb6, dial-up

Currently I'm developing a real-time stock market price list grabber in classic vb6 which will connect to the internet if there is no active internet connection. for internet connection process I used the code below using rasapi32.dll, But unfortunately it always returns ERROR CODE :- 621, The phone-book cannot be opened.

THE CODE IS

```
'This program let you dial to your dial-up connections using whether
'the stored user name and password or  the ones you specifies
'(It use RasDial for dialing)
'You need a form with a list,2 textbox and a command button
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (pDst As Any, ByVal pSrc As String, ByVal ByteLen As Long)
Private Declare Sub ZeroMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlZeroMemory" (Destination As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
Const RAS95_MaxEntryName = 256
Const RAS_MaxPhoneNumber = 128
Const RAS_MaxCallbackNumber = RAS_MaxPhoneNumber
Const UNLEN = 256
Const PWLEN = 256
Const DNLEN = 12
Private Type RASDIALPARAMS
   dwSize As Long ' 1052
   szEntryName(RAS95_MaxEntryName) As Byte
   szPhoneNumber(RAS_MaxPhoneNumber) As Byte
   szCallbackNumber(RAS_MaxCallbackNumber) As Byte
   szUserName(UNLEN) As Byte
   szPassword(PWLEN) As Byte
   szDomain(DNLEN) As Bytehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361069/how-can-i-access-hidden-class-variables-in-vb6
End Type
Private Type RASENTRYNAME95
    'set dwsize to 264
    dwSize As Long
    szEntryName(RAS95_MaxEntryName) As Byte
End Type
Private Declare Function RasDial Lib "rasapi32.dll" Alias "RasDialA" (ByVal lprasdialextensions As Long, ByVal lpcstr As String, ByRef lprasdialparamsa As RASDIALPARAMS, ByVal dword As Long, lpvoid As Any, ByRef lphrasconn As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RasEnumEntries Lib "rasapi32.dll" Alias "RasEnumEntriesA" (ByVal reserved As String, ByVal lpszPhonebook As String, lprasentryname As Any, lpcb As Long, lpcEntries As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RasGetEntryDialParams Lib "rasapi32.dll" Alias "RasGetEntryDialParamsA" (ByVal lpcstr As String, ByRef lprasdialparamsa As RASDIALPARAMS, ByRef lpbool As Long) As Long

Private Function Dial(ByVal Connection As String, ByVal UserName As String, ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    **Dim rp As RASDIALPARAMS, h As Long, resp As Long**
    rp.dwSize = Len(rp) + 6
    ChangeBytes Connection, rp.szEntryName
    ChangeBytes "", rp.szPhoneNumber 'Phone number stored for the connection
    ChangeBytes "*", rp.szCallbackNumber 'Callback number stored for the connection
    ChangeBytes UserName, rp.szUserName
    ChangeBytes Password, rp.szPassword
    ChangeBytes "*", rp.szDomain 'Domain stored for the connection
    'Dial
    resp = RasDial(ByVal 0, ByVal 0, rp, 0, ByVal 0, h)    'AddressOf RasDialFunc
    MsgBox resp
    Dial = (resp = 0)
End Function

Private Function ChangeToStringUni(Bytes() As Byte) As String
    'Changes an byte array  to a Visual Basic unicode string
    Dim temp As String
    temp = StrConv(Bytes, vbUnicode)
    ChangeToStringUni = Left(temp, InStr(temp, Chr(0)) - 1)
End Function

Private Function ChangeBytes(ByVal str As String, Bytes() As Byte) As Boolean
    'Changes a Visual Basic unicode string to an byte array
    'Returns True if it truncates str
    Dim lenBs As Long 'length of the byte array
    Dim lenStr As Long 'length of the string
    lenBs = UBound(Bytes) - LBound(Bytes)
    lenStr = LenB(StrConv(str, vbFromUnicode))
    If lenBs > lenStr Then
        CopyMemory Bytes(0), str, lenStr
        ZeroMemory Bytes(lenStr), lenBs - lenStr
    ElseIf lenBs = lenStr Then
        CopyMemory Bytes(0), str, lenStr
    Else
        CopyMemory Bytes(0), str, lenBs 'Queda truncado
        ChangeBytes = True
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dial List1.Text, Text1, Text2
End Sub

Private Sub List1_Click()
    Dim rdp As RASDIALPARAMS, t As Long
    rdp.dwSize = Len(rdp) + 6
    ChangeBytes List1.Text, rdp.szEntryName
    'Get User name and password for the connection
    t = RasGetEntryDialParams(List1.Text, rdp, 0)
    If t = 0 Then
        Text1 = ChangeToStringUni(rdp.szUserName)
        Text2 = ChangeToStringUni(rdp.szPassword)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    'example created by Daniel Kaufmann (daniel@i.com.uy)
    'load the connections
    Text2.PasswordChar = "*"
    Command1.Caption = "Dial"
    Dim s As Long, l As Long, ln As Long, a$
    ReDim r(255) As RASENTRYNAME95

    r(0).dwSize = 264
    s = 256 * r(0).dwSize
    l = RasEnumEntries(vbNullString, vbNullString, r(0), s, ln)
    For l = 0 To ln - 1
        a$ = StrConv(r(l).szEntryName(), vbUnicode)
        List1.AddItem Left$(a$, InStr(a$, Chr$(0)) - 1)
    Next
    If List1.ListCount > 0 Then
        List1.ListIndex = 0
        List1_Click
    End If
End Sub
```

Please help me

Comment: You're on SO for a year now and should know how to format code ... and only post relevant portions of it.

Comment: ya, I really don't know how to format code, & I'm sorry for that. But if you can understand the problem then please help me.

Comment: I'm just curious, you are developing an application "now," any particular reason why you are using vb6 and not vb.net?

Answer (score 0):

This may be no help at all, but googling turned up several suggestions that there may be missing components or a corrupt phonebook: [Error 621: Cannot Open Phonebook](http://rvwinkle1.tripod.com/dial-up_errors.htm#Error%20621%3a%20Cannot%20Open%20Phonebook)

Comment: I've already stormed the google, but I didn't found anything, my phonebook file is ok cause I've tested it using rasdial.exe or the normal Windows XP Dial-up process. I think that the problem is in above code, can please test it?